# Create a pipeline view in jquery or bootstrap

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a view similar to this: https://www.pipedrive.com/en/features/see-your-sales-pipeline

where a user can drag and drop a task from one side to another. JIRA also provides a similar view.

Can somebody please suggest a plugin of jquery or bootstrap which can be used in this case (preferably with django)?

Answer (score 0):

User jQuery UI dropable plugin. 'https://jqueryui.com/droppable/'